# SQL Server - Convert record per day into date range (with gaps)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have found a lot of questions and answers asking how to convert a date range to records per day, but I need the opposite and can't find anything yet.

So let's say I have this dataset:

```
User | Available
1    | 01-01-2019
1    | 02-01-2019
1    | 03-01-2019
1    | 04-01-2019
2    | 05-01-2019
2    | 06-01-2019
2    | 07-01-2019
2    | 10-01-2019
2    | 11-01-2019
2    | 12-01-2019
```

So we have user 1 who is available from 01/01/2019 to 04/01/2019. Then we have user 2 who is available from 05/01/2019 to 07/01/2019 and 10/01/2019 to 12/01/2019.

The result I am looking for should look like this:

```
User | Start      | End
1    | 01-01-2019 | 04-01-2019
2    | 05-01-2019 | 07-01-2019
2    | 10-01-2019 | 12-01-2019
```

User 1 was fairly easy to calculate using min/max dates, but with the gaps of user 2, I am completely lost. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to do this before somewhere too, this is the solution I used. Basically use a row number split by your grouping columns and ordered by date, and additionally calculate the amount of days from a particular date onwards (any hard-coded day will work).

The key here is that while the row number increases 1 by 1, the anchor difference will only increase 1 by 1 if the days are consecutive. Thus, the rest between the anchor diff and the row number will ***stay the same*** only if there are consecutive dates, allowing you to group by and calculate min/max.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Availabilities') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Availabilities

CREATE TABLE #Availabilities (
    [User] INT,
    Available DATE)

INSERT INTO #Availabilities
VALUES
    (1, '2019-01-01'),
    (1, '2019-01-02'),
    (1, '2019-01-03'),
    (1, '2019-01-04'),

    (2, '2019-01-05'),
    (2, '2019-01-06'),
    (2, '2019-01-07'),

    (2, '2019-01-10'),
    (2, '2019-01-11'),
    (2, '2019-01-12')


;WITH WindowFunctions AS
(
    SELECT
        A.[User],
        A.Available,
        AnchorDayDifference = DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-01-01', A.Available),
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.[User] ORDER BY A.Available)
    FROM
        #Availabilities AS A
)
SELECT
    T.[User],
    Start = MIN(T.Available),
    [End] = MAX(T.Available)
FROM
    WindowFunctions AS T
GROUP BY
    T.[User],
    T.AnchorDayDifference - T.RowNumber
```

Result:

```
User    Start       End
1       2019-01-01  2019-01-04
2       2019-01-05  2019-01-07
2       2019-01-10  2019-01-12
```

The `WindowFunctions` values are (added the posterior rest result):

```
User    Available   AnchorDayDifference RowNumber   GroupingRestResult
1       2019-01-01  365                 1           364
1       2019-01-02  366                 2           364
1       2019-01-03  367                 3           364
1       2019-01-04  368                 4           364
2       2019-01-05  369                 1           368
2       2019-01-06  370                 2           368
2       2019-01-07  371                 3           368
2       2019-01-10  374                 4           370
2       2019-01-11  375                 5           370
2       2019-01-12  376                 6           370
```

Comment: I like the "Anchor Day" solution; probably slight quicker than making use of `LEAD`/`LAG` to check the next/previous row.

Comment: It is indeed slightly quicker and works just like I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

This is a "common" Groups and Island question. Provided you're on SQL Server 2012+ (and if you're not, it's time to upgrade) this gets you the result you're after:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT V.[User],
           CONVERT(date,Available,105) AS Available
    FROM (VALUES(1,'01-01-2019'),
                (1,'02-01-2019'),
                (1,'03-01-2019'),
                (1,'04-01-2019'),
                (2,'05-01-2019'),
                (2,'06-01-2019'),
                (2,'07-01-2019'),
                (2,'10-01-2019'),
                (2,'11-01-2019'),
                (2,'12-01-2019')) V([User],Available)),
Diffs AS(
    SELECT V.[User],
           V.Available,
           DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(V.Available,1,DATEADD(DAY, -1, V.Available)) OVER (PARTITION BY V.[User] ORDER BY V.Available), V.Available) AS Diff
    FROM VTE V),
Groups AS(
    SELECT D.[User],
           D.Available,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN D.Diff > 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY D.[User] ORDER BY D.Available
                                                        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM Diffs D)
SELECT G.[User],
       MIN(G.Available) AS [Start],
       MAX(G.Available) AS [End]
FROM Groups G
GROUP BY G.[User],
         G.Grp
ORDER BY G.[User],
         [Start];
```

The first CTE `Diffs`, excluding `VTE` ("Value Table Expression") for the sample data, gets the difference in days between the different rows. The second CTE `Groups` then puts the dates into groups (surprise that), base on if the difference was more than 1. Then we can use those groups to get a `MIN` and `MAX` for that group in the final `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reading as MONTHS not DAYS

**Example**

```
Select [User]
      ,[Start] = min([Available])
      ,[End]   = max([Available])
 From ( 
        Select * 
              ,Grp = DateDiff(MONTH,'1900-01-01',[Available]) - Row_Number() over (Partition By [User] Order by [Available])
         From  YourTable
      ) A
 Group By [User],[Grp]
```

**Returns**

```
User    Start       End
1       2019-01-01  2019-04-01
2       2019-05-01  2019-07-01
2       2019-10-01  2019-12-01
```